# Integral problem, how do I solve?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^a  e^{1-2x}\, dx = \frac e4$$

My problem is solving for $a$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Use MathJaX to write here, or very few people will even attempt to understand what you wrote.

Comment: Are you able to compute the integral?  Hint:  $e^{1-2x}=e\times e^{-2x}$.

Comment: sorry I have been having trouble writing in mathjax,

Comment: Yes I am able to compute the integral, my issue is solving with e

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your computation of the integral?

Comment: @SaraBlank That $\;e\;$ multiplying there is *only a constant*: take it out of the integral!

Comment: $/e\int{0_a} e^(-2x)

Comment: Yes, you can bring the constant out.  Can you actually compute the integral?

Comment: Yes I could and i got 1/2(e-e^(1-2a))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way to solve it using a change of variable (Even though it is easier to factor out one $e$ of course...):
$$
t = 1 -2x \\
dt = -2 dx \implies dx = \frac{-dt}{2} \\ 
x = 0 \implies t = 1-2\cdot 0 = 1\\
x = a \implies t = 1-2a
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^a e^{1-2x} = \int_1^{1-2a} e^t \cdot \frac{-dt}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} [e^t]^{1-2a}_1 = -\frac{1}{2} (e^{1-2a}-e)
$$
So you want 
$$
 -\frac{1}{2} (e^{1-2a}-e) = e/4 \implies -\frac{1}{2}(e^{-2a} -1) = 1/4 \implies e^{-2a} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Taking log :
$$
-2a = -\ln(2) \implies a = \ln(2)/2
$$

Comment: I understood everything...except from how you get from -1/2(e^1-2a -e) =e/4, to it equalling 1/4

Comment: $(e^{1-2a}-e) = e(e^{-2a}-1)$
So you then divide by $e$ on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}&e^{1-2x}=e\cdot e^{-2x}\\{}\\
&\int e^{kx}dx=\frac1ke^x+C\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. Substitute $u=-2x$ and $\text{d}u=-2\space\text{d}x$
   $$\int e^{1-2x}\space\text{d}x=\int e\cdot e^{-2x}\space\text{d}x=e\int e^{-2x}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{e}{2}\int e^u\space\text{d}u=\text{C}-\frac{e^{1-2x}}{2}$$
2. $$\int_0^ae^{1-2x}\space\text{d}x=\left[-\frac{e^{1-2x}}{2}\right]_0^a=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left[e^{1-2x}\right]_0^a=-\frac{e^{1-2a}-e^{1-2\cdot0}}{2}=\frac{e-e^{1-2a}}{2}$$
3. $$\int_0^ae^{1-2x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{e}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{e-e^{1-2a}}{2}=\frac{e}{4}\Longleftrightarrow a=\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$$